# is there an OpenID client for Java that works for non-web applications?

Tags: java, openid, non-web

As stated in openid.net: "OpenID is a safe, faster, and easier way to log in to web sites". is it true ONLY for web sites?

Is there an OpenID client *for Java* that works for non-web applications?